# Extend a class from an external library with a static function in a typesafe manner in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, static, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to extend the rxjs5 `Observable` class with a **static** function. I can to this in plain JavaScript:

```
var myStaticFn = function() { /* ... */ };
Observable.myStaticFn = myStaticFn;
```

this works, but in TypeScript I can't aaccess `Observable.myStaticFn` as the property `myStaticFn` is not known on the class `Observable`.

How do I declare/augment the rxjs5 Module `Observable` class, so that I can access my function in a type-safe manner?

*Note: As a starting point, the following shows an example how to extend a **non-static** function to the Observable (for example to create a custom rxjs Operator), and this completely works but is not what I want!*

```
function myOperator(this: Observable<any>): Observable<any> = function(){ /*...*/ };
Observable.prototype.myOperator = myOperator;

declare module "rxjs/Observable" {
    interface Observable<T> {
        myOperator: typeof myOperator;
    }
}
```

The above works, because the `declare` syntax of TypeScript allows me to treat the `Observable` as an interface, and interfaces can be augmented/merged. But there is no way in TypeScript to declare a **static** function on an interface.

It is also not feasible to derive from the `Observable` class, say `ExtendedObservable` because every user of my code would have to use the `ExtendedObservable` type instead of the `Observable` type throughout the project, and the concept additionally fails if I want to put different static methods on the Observable, depending on the imported modules.

Comment: There is an open issue for the lack of static modifier on interfaces now https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it out myself looking [at the implementation of the static `.from()` extension in the RxJS source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/add/observable/from.ts):

```
import { myStaticFn as myStaticFnStatic } from "./myStaticFn";

declare module "rxjs/Observable" {
    namespace Observable {
        let myStaticFn: myStaticFnStatic;
    }
}
```

Note how I import `myStaticFn` but scope it locally to the name `myStaticFnStatic` - this is required else you get a compiler error.

Comment: Dyna this is exactly my solution, just as I have mentioned, Microsoft has changed the term "internal module" to "namespace".

Answer (score 0):

In the definition file for rx you have the definition for the [Observable](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/rx/rx.d.ts#L28) class and the [ObservableStatic](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/rx/rx.d.ts#L47).
If you want to add static functions then you need to augment the `ObservableStatic`:

```
declare module "rxjs/Observable" {
    interface ObservableStatic {
        myOperator: typeof myOperator;
    }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately only applies to rxjs v <= 4.0. I am specifically looking for a RxJS v5 (currently in rc-1) solution. On rxjs5, there is no ObservableStatic class anymore.

Comment: Seems that the new version is completely rewritten in typescript, and there's no definition file, you just probably use the source right?

Comment: No I am using the CommonJS module, which has type annotation for every *.ts file i.e. `node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts` that are used by the TS compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a module with the same name of the interface. Inside the module you write the static functions. This is the best practice in TypeScript. It's called "module merging".

Reference: [Pro TypeScript](https://github.com/shootthepoets/information-technology-ebooks/blob/master/%5BTYPESCRIPT%5D%5BPro%20TypeScript%20Application-Scale%20JavaScript%20Development%5D.pdf) pages #40 #41

Just one notice: Microsoft has changed the term "internal module" to "namespace" since this book was wrriten: [Namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html)

Comment: can you add some code, possibly using the `Observable` examples from my question?

Comment: Module Augmentation does not work in in this case, because you can't declare a function on an interface as __static__

Comment: @Dyna I'm sorry I don't have enough time to create such code and test it. Just learn the topic of "module merging" in the book I've referenced. It starts in the end of page 40, and it's very short and to the point. Because you'll have a nested module it might be a little bit tricky, but this is the solution.

Comment: After reading page 40/41 the section `Module Merging` I think the mentioned approach there works only when using internal modules in TS. When using external modules, I can't create `module Observable {}` as this will always result in an error "Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Observable' "

Comment: @Dyna it will work fine, just one thing: since this book was written, Microsoft has changed the name of "internal module" to "namespace". So instead of writing "module Observable", write "namespace Observable". You can't create this module again but you can use the same namespace that this module has automatically created: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Comment: Turns out with namespace it will work, found it in the RxJS5 source where it is used the same way.